# Database Insertion not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why is the code below not inserting anything into the database table?

```
require_once"connection.php";
$target_Path='img/displays/';
$caption=$_POST['caption'];
$albums=$_POST['albums'];
$target_Path = $target_Path.basename($_FILES['photo']['name'] );
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target_Path);
$withoutExt = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $target_Path);
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `ett`.`gallery` (`id` ,`album`,`name`,`path`)VALUES (`NULL`,`".$albums."`,`".$caption."`,`".$withoutExt."`)");
```

The code below works fine, but for some reasons the query above is not working. What is the problem?

```
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `ett`.`gallery` (`id`, `album`, `name`, `path`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'test', 'test')");
```

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file to _read_ what exactly the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: echo the query and try to write in direct database so that you can confirm query is correct or not

Comment: why id is always null?

Comment: cause it's auto increment so I put it on NULL

Comment: Don't use backticks for values, use single quotes. And nothing around null values.

Comment: Thank you Qirel, that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes should be used around string values, not backticks

```
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `ett`.`gallery` (`id` ,`album`,`name`,`path`)VALUES (NULL,'".$albums."','".$caption."','".$withoutExt."')");
```

Comment: The link Qirel provided has much more info. Please refer that also even though this solves your problem

Comment: Thank you guys, both the link and your answer were useful

Comment: @MustafaAzad You are welcome :)